# Why is a comparison in my if statement effecting the output

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a jump function into my game and the 3rd part my if statement is affecting how high the jump is instead making sure you jump under. Like if I put 2 instead of 1.001f it will jump high but if it's 1.1 it barely jumps. Also, 1.001 doesn't seem to work at all.

```
public float jumpForce = 300f;
```

This code has no jump

```
if (Input.GetKey("space") && rb.position.y < 1.001f)
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

This code does a little jump

```
if (Input.GetKey("space") && rb.position.y < 1.1f)
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

And this code does a high jump

```
if (Input.GetKey("space") && rb.position.y < 2f)
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the exact code that is causing small jumps and the exact code that is causing large jumps. Please run both sets of code to confirm the behaviour before sharing it with us. Also share the **exact** value of `jumpForce` for both of the code samples (check the value, don't guess).

Comment: My guess is that the code is running multiple times (not just a single time). As it runs, the value of `rb.position.y` increases such that it then (in subsequent executions) no longer enters the `if`. So, as an example, maybe the code ends up running only 10 times rather than 20. To you, that looks like a smaller jump.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments simply the higher your threshold the more often the line will be executed before the threshold height is reached => the force will be added more often.

To avoid that you should rather only do the jump once e.g. on `GetKeyDown` instead and add a fixed force instead of using `Time.deltaTime` like

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && rb.position.y < 1.001f)
{
    rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```